# How to pass a value for a binding focus state in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I pass a value to a binding focus state in SwiftUI for a preview? I understand that FocusState.Binding can be used to pass a binding value to @FocusState. This works fine in live use, but I'm not sure how to pass a value for it in a preview.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var focused: FocusState<Bool>.Binding
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text)
            .focused(focused)
    }
}

// Error: Type 'FocusState<Bool>.Binding' has no member 'constant'
#Preview {
    ContentView(text: .constant("Hello World"), focused: .constant(true))
}
```

Comment: You can try this ```ContentView(text: .constant("Hello World"), focused: FocusState<Bool>().projectedValue)```

Comment: I think it will pass the compiler, however, you can not provide a default value for mock testing/mock previewing. @RajaKishan

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a `constant` focus state binding, because the focus state must always be changeable, either by the user tapping on the text field, or by iOS popping up alerts, or otherwise.

Therefore, you must declare a `@FocusState` somewhere, and use the binding from that. You can set it to a desired initial value in `onAppear`, but after that it can be changed. That said, since this is for previews, this shouldn't be much of a problem.

You can write a `View` that gives you a focus state binding as a closure parameter.

```
struct FocusStateProvider<Content: View, Value: Hashable>: View {
    let state: FocusState<Value>
    let constant: Value
    let content: (FocusState<Value>.Binding) -> Content
    
    init(constant value: Value, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (FocusState<Value>.Binding) -> Content)
        where Value == Bool {
        self.content = content
        self.constant = value
        self.state = FocusState()
    }
    
    init<T>(constant value: Value, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (FocusState<Value>.Binding) -> Content)
        where Value == T? {
        self.content = content
        self.constant = value
        self.state = FocusState()
    }

    var body: some View {
        content(state.projectedValue)
            .onAppear {
                state.wrappedValue = constant
            }
    }
}
```

This handles both `Bool` and `T?` focus states. If you only need one of them, you can remove one of the initialisers, and possibly remove the `Value` type parameter.

Usage:

```
#Preview {
    FocusStateProvider(initial: true) {
        ContentView(text: .constant("Foo"), focused: $0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I found I can just use @FocusState in the preview.

Comment: @BerryBlue Ah, so you don't actually need an initial value for the focus state? In that case passing `FocusState<Bool>().projectedValue` like [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77762417/how-to-pass-a-value-for-a-binding-focus-state-in-swiftui/77763568?noredirect=1#comment137092877_77762417) suggests would have been fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I found it works if I just create a `@FocusState` variable in the preview itself.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var focused: FocusState<Bool>.Binding
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text)
            .focused(focused)
    }
}

#Preview {
    @FocusState var focused: Bool
    return ContentView(text: .constant("Hello World"), focused: $focused)
}
```